# High memory usage on SQL Server running on Linux

Tags: sql-server, linux

I've had SQL Server running on a VM Linux box running lubuntu (20.04) without problems for over 2 years.  For some reason my VM reset to only run on 1 Core.  I fixed it (run 4 cores), my memory usage is very high and seems to get higher.  I'm the only one using the SQL server for application in-house connecting to C# application. There are no queries running and then application is not running but I still have the below high usage.

Not sure where I need to look to fix the issue.

[image]

Comment: SQL Server uses as much RAM as it needs to. Have you limited the amount it should be using and it's using more than you've asked it to?

Comment: most SQL platforms pre-allocate memory so they can manage it better.  You can change that in the setting to the DB server.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to load an image to show the issue.  Using HOP, it says I'm using 20.8g (VIRT) and 5.1g(RES) on an 8GB RAM allocation

Comment: This is by design, for performance reasons. SQL Server caches a multitude of things in Memory, including the actual data from your Tables that were recently used.

Comment: So the problem is that my c# application is timing out when it tries to pull data.  Even just running a standard Select 1000 * from TABLE is timing out.  Any ideas what I need to do to fix this.  It was working great for over 2 years and now the server is extremely slow.

Comment: Is the C# app running on the same server as your SQL Server instance?

Comment: No it is not.  The C# application is running locally and it is not on.

Answer (score 0):

So as it turns out, the problem was that a core table had over 2 million duplicated records so it was timing out my application.  I believed it was a server problem when I saw the stats. Once I cleared the duplicates, it worked properly.

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to close the question out.